# Выводит на одну меньше. То есть последний не выводит

Tags: php, mysql, веб-программирование

```
    $num=$_POST["name"];



$orders_all = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `order_phone`='".$num."'" ,$link); 


If (mysql_num_rows($orders_all) > 0)
      {
        $row_reviews = mysql_fetch_array($query_reviews);
      do

      {

        echo "В таблице mytable ".mysql_num_rows($orders_all)." записей";

$order_id= mysql_fetch_array($orders_all);

$order_all=mysql_query("SELECT  * FROM `buy_products` WHERE `buy_id_order`='".$order_id["order_id"]."'",$link);

$buy_id_product= mysql_fetch_array($order_all);

$product_info=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table_products` WHERE `products_id`='".$buy_id_product["buy_id_product"]."'",$link);

$pi=mysql_fetch_array($product_info);

$title=$pi["title"];

$buy_cart_size=$buy_id_product["buy_cart_size"];

$buy_count_product=$buy_id_product["buy_count_product"];

$total_price=$order_id["total_price"];

$order_fio=$order_id["order_fio"];

$order_city=$order_id["order_city"];

$order_number_np=$order_id["order_number_np"];

$order_phone=$order_id["order_phone"];

$order_confirmed=$order_id["order_confirmed"];

$consignmentnumber=$order_id["consignmentnumber"];
      echo '

          <p class="author-date" align="center"><strong><br>ЗАКАЗЫ</strong></p>

          <p class="author-date" align="center"><br>'.$order_phone.'</p>

          <p class="author-date" align="center"><strong><br>Наименование товара: </strong>, '.$title.'</p>

          <p class="author-date" align="center"><strong><br>Размер: </strong>, '.$buy_cart_size.'</p>

          <p class="author-date" align="center"><strong><br>Количество: </strong>, '.$buy_count_product.'</p>

          <p class="author-date" align="center"><strong><br>Цена: </strong>, '.$total_price.'</p>

          <p class="author-date" align="center"><br>Данные для отправки</p>

          <p class="author-date" align="center"><strong><br>Ф.И.О: </strong>, '.$order_fio.'</p>

          <p class="author-date" align="center"><strong><br>Город: </strong>, '.$order_city.'</p>

          <p class="author-date" align="center"><strong><br>Отделение: </strong>, '.$order_number_np.'</p>

          <p class="author-date" align="center"><strong><br>Моб. номер </strong>, '.$order_phone.'</p>

          <p class="author-date" align="center"><strong><br>Статус заказа: </strong>, '.$order_confirmed.'</p>

          <p class="author-date" align="center"><strong><br>Номер накладной: </strong>, '.$consignmentnumber.'</p>

      ';

      }
       while ($row_reviews = mysql_fetch_array($orders_all));
      }

      else
      {
          echo '<center>Нет.</center>';
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому `do {...} while()` так работает. Замени его на `while() {...}` и всё станет хорошо.